# Unusual jQuery syntax is puzzling me. Concatenation inside the $

Tags: jquery

I saw this jQuery code:

```
$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/done",
      data: { id: item_id },
      }).done(function(data) {
        if(data.status == 'done') {
          $("#" + data.id + " a.done").text('Not done')
          $("#" + data.id + " .item").wrapInner("<del>");
        }
     })
```

This syntax is confusing me:

```
$("#" + data.id + " a.done")
```

This is my DOM:

```
<li id="4">
  <span class="item">todo2</span>
  <span class="pull-right">            
    <a href="#" class="btn done">Done</a><a href="/delete/4" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
  </span>
</li>
```

So I thought the jQuery code was grabbing an element that read `#("#4 a.done")` but it seems to be grabbing a whole bunch of stuff from the `a` link tag , the li id, and the class done from the a link. What is going on there while selecting the DOM elements?

Comment: This is the derived form `"#4 a.done"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#" + data.id + " a.done")
```

evaluates to

```
#4 a.done
```

with a space between `4` and  `a.done`. This is selecting all `a`s with class `done` below the `li` with `id="4"`.

Answer (score 1):

Basically `id` of an element **should not** start with a number.

This is the derived form of `"#" + data.id + " a.done"` is `"#4 a.done"`. There is a space between `#4` and `a.done` That means element with  `a.done` inside element with id `4`